# IndexOutOfRangeException (C#) vs ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(Java)

Tags: java, c#, .net, exception

I'am just implementing a cool and simple board (chess board style) game for a friend of mine.
Since he wants the game to run either on android and on Windows Desktop, I'am implementing the android version in Android Studio with java and the Windows Desktop Version in VS2019 C# .NET.

I'am now trying to port the following java exception to C# .NET; here's the java code:

```
package eu.georgtoth.game.exceptions;

import eu.georgtoth.game.constants.BOARDCOLUMN;
import java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException;
import java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException;
/**
 * BoardIndexOutOfBoundsException extends {@link ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException}
 * thrown, when column {@link BOARDCOLUMN} and row {@link Integer} are out of board bounces!
 */
public class BoardIndexOutOfBoundsException extends ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    /**
     * constructor with message calling super ctor {@link ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(String s)}
     * @param message {@link String} for exception message
     */
    public BoardIndexOutOfBoundsException(String message) { super(message); }

    /**
     * constructor with message and inner exception using {@link #initCause(Throwable throwable)}
     * @param message {@link String} detailed exception message
     * @param throwable {@link Throwable} for inner exception 
     */
    public BoardIndexOutOfBoundsException(String message, Throwable throwable) {
        this(message);
        super.initCause(throwable);
    }

    /**
     * constructor with board column and row indexer, calling base ctor 
     *   with inner exception (@link IndexOutOfBoundsException) as Throwable {@link Throwable}
     * @param column board {@link BOARDCOLUMN} column indexer
     * @param row    board {@link Integer} row indexer
     */
    public BoardIndexOutOfBoundsException(BOARDCOLUMN column, int row) {
        this("board accessor out of bounce at field: " + column.getName() + row,
            ((IndexOutOfBoundsException) 
                (new Throwable("out of bounds at colunn=" + column.getValue() + ", row=" + row))));
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

I've the following problems / questions:

1. There is no detailed concrete ArrayIndexOutOfSomeWhatException in C# and only [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0).
2. [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0) is a sealed (some kind of framework) class and can't be inherited.
3. But there is another "out of some what" exception in .NET, called [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0#see-also)

I still don't exactly semantically understand full the some kind of more flat hierarchy of .NET exceptions with many similiar siblings (leaf nodes) in the Exception sub class tree.
(a tragedy after 8 years expirience in C# .NET)

Can somebody explain, when [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0) should be used and when [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0#see-also) is semantically correct?

What whould be the semantically correct choice in that case?

- Calling simple [IndexOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.indexoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0) without derived class. (don't looks like stylish code)?
- Caling simple [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0)?
- Implementing a framework sub class derived from [ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentoutofrangeexception?view=net-5.0#see-also)?

Kind regards, heinrich.

p.s.: I know this question is a pedantic quirk, but I really don't understand the exact formal differences here. (Normally in a job under time pressure I would have already implemented some variant after consultation with colleagues (vote or boss determined), but the exception hierarchy of .NET in contrast to Java, is not completely consistently understandable for me.

Comment: IndexOutOfRangeException is mostly thrown by the framework if array element is accessed with invalid index value. If you want to throw exception based on the user's input of ChessBoard's co-ordinates, you should throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException or may be your own exception inherited from ArgumentOutOfRangeException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IndexOutOfRangeException is for when you attempt to access an element of an array or collection with an index out of range. For example, accessing the 11th element of an array of size 10.

ArgumentOutOfRangeException does not involve arrays. It is used when a value is out of range. For example, setting someone's birthday to the 13th month.

Which should you extend? Board index out of bounds sounds a bit like someone attempted to locate something with an index that is out of range. It seems like IndexOutOfRangeException is a defensible choice. However, it extends SystemException which may not be appropriate for your Application's exception.

Is there any reason why you don't just extend Exception? It's what Microsoft's documentation seems to suggest:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-create-user-defined-exceptions

Their best practices document suggests using the built-in exceptions where possible. Is IndexOutOfRangeException unsuitable for you?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/best-practices-for-exceptions